# Efficient Way to Categorize

Tags: stata

I have a sting variable, call it `desc`, that takes on many different values, say 300. I want to create two new variables, `desc_a` and `desc_b`. `desc` contains two classes of values; I want to put those belonging to the first class in `desc_a` and the rest in `desc_b`. I will describe one way I came up with. However, this method is very slow. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
gen desc_a = ""
gen desc_b = ""
tab desc
```

The resulting tab output might show up like (omitting irrelevant information):

```
DESC                  |  Freq.  Perc.  Cum.
___________________________________________
First Element of a       53
Second Element of a      22
First Element of b       78
Third Element of a       232
Second Element of b      33
```

*Manually go through and copy and paste each string of the tab into statements such as:

```
replace desc_a = "First Element of a" if desc=="First Element of a"
replace desc_a = "Second Element of a" if desc=="Second Element of a"
replace desc_a = "Third Element of a" if desc=="Third Element of a"
...
replace desc_b = "First Element of b" if desc=="First Element of b"
replace desc_b = "Second Element of b" if desc=="Second Element of b"
```

Note that the actual data don't actually follow a nice pattern like this and so I can't automate it by regular expressions or something similar. I do need to manually inspect each one and decide which category it would go in. I do think, however, that the method I have described which involves tons of copying and pasting isn't the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Stata Data Editor window will help reduce your effort.

Create a Stata dataset containing two variables: the 300 distinct values of desc, and a variable, I'll call it ab, initialized to missing. Then open the dataset in the Stata Data Editor and go down the observations, replacing (by typing in the cells) the missing values with an indicator of whether the description belongs in group a or b (say 1 or 2). Then save that dataset and merge it with your original dataset, and use the merged value ab to assign the description to the appropriate variable.

```
generate desc_a = desc if ab==1
generate desc_b = desc if ab==2
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @William's solution

```
* recreate your data example
clear
input str19 desc int n
"First Element of a" 53 
"Second Element of a" 22 
"First Element of b " 78 
"Third Element of a" 232 
"Second Element of b" 33 
end
expand n
set seed 314324
gen somedata = runiform()
sort somedata
tab des
tempfile main
save "`main'"

* reduce to one observation per value of desc
bysort desc: keep if _n == 1
keep desc

* make an effort to identify a or b, note that
* the following fails for one obs
gen ab = regexs(1) if regexm(desc,"(a|b)$")

* save and edit manually
tempfile toedit
save "`toedit'"

* this is simulated editing...
clear
input str19 desc str1 ab
"First Element of a" "a" 
"First Element of b " "b" 
"Second Element of a" "a" 
"Second Element of b" "b" 
"Third Element of a" "a" 
end

* now combine with the original data
merge 1:m desc using "`main'", assert(match) nogen
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best, but it is an improvement over my above solution:

```
gen desc_a = ""
replace 
replace desc_a = desc if desc=="First Element of a"
replace desc_a = desc if desc=="Second Element of a"
replace desc_a = desc if desc=="Third Element of a"
...

replace desc_b = desc if desc_a==""
```